# Reverse SSH Tunnel problem

Tags: ssh, maas

I have an existing setup as follows, 
workstation <-> Maas server <-> VM's.

The Maas server has two interfaces, eth0 has a static address of 192.168.x.x and the eth1 has 10.4.x.x. eth1 is also acting as DHCP manager for the VM's. My workstation's ip is 10.x.x.x and I can ssh the Maas server. The Maas server in turn is also ssh connect to the VM's. Because the workstation and VM's are on a different network I can't connect to the VM's directly.

I tried reverse SSH tunneling with,

```
ssh -R 6333:localhost:22 akh@192.168.x.x
```

from one of the VM's to the Maas server. Afterwards I tried to connect from my workstation to the VM using,

```
ssh akh@192.168.x.x -p 6333
```

But I repeatedly get this error, 'Permission denied (publickey).'

I have already copied my public key to in the VM's authorized key files, but I get same error. Is there maybe another method to connect from the workstation to the VM ! If so, please advise.

Comment: If you use `ssh -v` (verbose) you will have an hint on where it is failing --- maybe it can help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me suggest you to use sshuttle, it easily creates a 'vpn' over ssh in your workstation run the following commands:

```
$ sudo apt-get install sshuttle
$ sshuttle -r akh@192.168.x.x 10.x.x.x/24  # /24 is the subnet
```

Then in another terminal (also in workstation) you should be able connect automagically to any host in 10.x.x.x/24 subnet.

I do this all the time, I really recommend you to use sshuttle.

Comment: do you also use the sshuttle to connect to the instances created in the compute node !

Comment: if the instances get a 10.x.x.x/24 IP then you'll be able to connect transparently, that's my case for floating IPs. I'm not sure if sshuttle can be used jump twice to reach a host.

Answer (score 1):

You can configure your MaaS server to route between your workstation and the target VMs.

Enable IP forwarding:
    echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward

To ensure it is persisted, you should also edit /etc/sysctl.conf and make sure that the line `net.ipv4.ip_forward=1` is not commented.

Then, you can add a static route on your workstation that redirects the traffic for the VMs through the MaaS server. Assuming that your workstation is running ubuntu, you can execute this command:

```
route add -net 10.4.x.x netmask 255.255.0.0 gw 192.168.x.x
```

You should also persist this static route in /etc/network/interfaces.

This is valid for recent Ubuntu version, I have tested it on 12.04 and newer.